# How is a complex elliptic curve a torus?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, number-theory, elliptic-curves, topological-groups

I have been learning about elliptic curves. In particular, I have been trying to understand the proof that an elliptic curve (let's assume it's nonsingular, if it matters), say $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b=:f(x)$ over $\mathbb C$ is always isomorphic as a topological group to $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$ (that of course depends on the coefficients $a,b$).

I think that I can follow the argument based on showing that the Weierstrass $\wp$-function works as such an isomorphism. However, I cannot reconcile this with my mental picture about what an elliptic curve looks like. Just topologically, I don't see how $E(\mathbb C)$ could possibly be homeomorphic to a torus.

Let's assume that $f$ has distinct roots $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Then, for every $x$ in the complex plane except for these three points, there are exactly two corresponding values of $y$ on the elliptic curve due to the fundamental theorem of algebra. Therefore, my naïve mental picture for $E(\mathbb C)$ is that of two infinite planes joined at $3$ points corresponding to the roots of $f$. Even accounting for the points at infinity, my mental image ends up being something like a sphere "squashed down" such that the northern and southern hemispheres touch at three points.

What I described doesn't seem like it could be possibly homeomorphic to a torus, although I have to admit I cannot prove this rigorously.

What's gone wrong in my logic? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://people.math.harvard.edu/~jeffs/Elliptic_Curves.pdf here's an explaination why double cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ ramified at four points is a torus.

Comment: Take a look at section 8.1 of Penrose's Road to reality. There's a nice visualization of $y^2=x^3-1$.

Comment: There is an explanation with IMO useful pictures in Keith Kendig's *Elementary Algebraic Geometry*, Springer GTM series 44, pages 14-15. More specifically the curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x+1)$. He also covers hyperelliptic curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at $y^2 = x$ first. This doesn't look like two planes glued together at a point, it looks like one plane folded in on itself rotationally (the ray of intersection is an artifact of being immersed in 3-dimensions).

[image: Riemann surface]

For an elliptic curve, the picture is we have a torus and then there's this skewer through the centre of it ($\phi$) and when we do the same kind of rotational fold, we get 4, so-called "rammification points" where the skewer intersects the torus.

There are some pictures [in the notes here](https://dmargalit7.math.gatech.edu/classes/math6421Fall2021/notes/Math6421.pdf) around pages 25 to 27.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my confusion was because it's impossible to have a smooth surface in 3-space (which my pictorial intuition was implicitly using) in such a way that every vertical line except a finite number cuts the surface exactly twice, but this is possible in 4 dimensions? Does that sound accurate?

Comment: @YiFan So the usual context for an elliptic curve is in $\mathbf{C}^2$ rather than $\mathbf{R}^3$ and one needs some sort of immersion to picture them in 3-space. But the fundamental misunderstanding is with how to picture $y^2 = x$: when you take a square root of a complex number, you halve the angle and that gives you this rotational folding.

Comment: Yeah, I think my visualisation of the surface was taking place implicitly in $\mathbb R^3$ without realising it, although I of course consciously knew I was trying to see something in $\mathbb C^2$. In this case then it wouldn't have been possible to get a surface with the desired properties without unwanted intersections, which is why I assumed we needed two separate planes, leading to the wrong image of $y^2=x$. I knew about the folding but thought it shouldn't matter since I was only interested in the topology, so I neglected it, I guess to my demise.

Answer (score 5):

One way to think of the elliptic curve
$$ E\!: y = x^3 + ax + b = (x-e_1)(x-e_2)(x-e_3) $$
is as
$$ y = f(x) := \sqrt{(x-e_1)(x-e_2)(x-e_3)}. $$
The Riemann surface of $\,y = f(x)\,$ (just as $\,y = \sqrt{x}\,$)
is two-sheeted or two valued over the extended complex plane
(Riemann sphere).
This can be understood with the use of branch cuts. For the function
$\,f(x)\,$ there is a cut from, say, $e_1$ to $e_2$ and another
from $e_3$ to $\infty$. With the cuts, the sphere is homeomorphic to
an annulus, a cylinder, or to a torus sliced in half. Gluing this
half torus with a copy of itself forms a complete torus. Of course,
the four points $\,e_1,e_2,e_3,\infty$ are ramification points just
as for the two points $0,\infty$ for $\sqrt{x}$. This may be hard
to visualize, but if you can understand the the Riemann surface for
$\sqrt{x}$ first, then it is not so hard.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having trouble visualising this, but your answer was helpful.

Comment: @YiFan Thanks for that comment! I have added a few more words.